# How to dynamically convert an list of strings into key value pair using dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a below input where I have key "Actual_Amount" which is a list of strings. I want to convert this key into multiple keys based on the no of values in the string.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "Billing_ID": "Default",
    "Product": "License Fee",
    "Region": "EMEA",
    "Actual_Amount": "0,49902.95,0"
  },
  {
    "Billing_ID": "Default",
    "Product": "License Fee",
    "Region": "APAC",
    "Actual_Amount": "0,0,0,0,0"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "Billing_ID": "Default",
    "Product": "License Fee",
    "Region": "EMEA",
    "Actual_Amount_1": "0",
    "Actual_Amount_2": "49902.95",
    "Actual_Amount_3": "0"
  },
  {
    "Billing_ID": "Default",
    "Product": "License Fee",
    "Region": "APAC",
    "Actual_Amount_1": "0",
    "Actual_Amount_2": "0",
    "Actual_Amount_3": "0",
    "Actual_Amount_4": "0",
    "Actual_Amount_5": "0"
  }
]
```

I tried to convert Actual_Amount into array and try but could not get the desired output.

Can someone help me with this?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split comma separated amount using [splitBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-splitby) and iterate over it using [map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-core-functions-map)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map{
    ($ - "Actual_Amount"),
    ($.Actual_Amount splitBy "," map(item,index)-> {
        ("Actual_Amount_" ++ (index + 1)): item
    })
}
```

Comment: It is important to note that the script also uses the object destructor: https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/dataweave/concatenation-dataweave-functions-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload map ((item, index) -> {
    Billing_ID: item.Billing_ID,
    Product: item.Product,
    Region: item.Region,
    (item.Actual_Amount splitBy  "," map ((item, index) -> {
        ("Actual_Amount_" ++ index +1):item
    }))
} )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**